# FusionCharts - VueJS - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when adding clip to xAxis

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fusioncharts

When I add a clip array to `xAxis` I'm getting a RangeError. Has anyone similar problems?

I've created a repo to show the bug: https://github.com/Ic3m4n34/fusioncharts-bug (App.vue)

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Which file is it...?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention: App.vue

Comment: Try with xAxis: [], 

, and add that value.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work :-(
tried: xAxis: {} and xAxis: { clip:[] }

Comment: @Ic3m4n - Check out this sandbox demo, based on your implementation - https://codesandbox.io/s/combination-charts-jcghn

Comment: @Zapdos13 I see the same error that I have in my app

Comment: @Ic3m4n- Take a look here https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9081

Comment: Thanks @Zapdos13, this actually explains everything

Comment: @Ic3m4n Do share the solution so that it could be used as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: it's connected to this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9081